# How can I set the exact height of a listbox in Windows Forms (C#)?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, height

I've been having some difficulties with setting the height of a listbox.

Code like this...

```
listbox1.Height = some_number;
```

... works only for some numbers. It seems that height of listbox may be only multiplication of height of its element. Is there a way how to "override" this behaviour?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try,

```
listbox1.IntegralHeight=false;
listbox1.Height=some_int_number;
```

Answer (score 12):

First, set

```
listbox1.IntegralHeight = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

For VBA-code:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ListBox1").ScaleWidth some_relate_numb, msoFalse, _     msoScaleFromTopLeft

listbox1.IntegralHeight=false

listbox1.Height=some_int_number
```